# Equivalent of gmtime in Julia?

Tags: time, timezone, julia, strftime

Julia has `strftime` as a built-in but not `gmtime`.

```
julia> strftime
strftime (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> gmtime
ERROR: gmtime not defined
```

What is the preferred Julia way to do the equivalent of `gmtime`? The idea is to turn seconds since the epoch into a time structure in the Z (+00:00) time zone. Here in Los Angeles, I see:

```
julia> strftime("%H:%M:%S", 0)
"16:00:00"
```

I would like to see `"00:00:00"`. I can do it in Python:

```
>>> from time import strftime, gmtime
>>> strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime(0))
'00:00:00'
```

I tried to use `ccall` in Julia but it did not work

```
julia> ccall( (:gmtime, "libc"), TmStruct, (Int64,), 0)
TmStruct(1590498096,32767,16041550,1,-1924564896,32744,1,0,0,0,0,0,1590498144,32767)

julia> strftime("%H:%M:%S", ans)
"16041550:32767:1590498096"
```

What went wrong with my `ccall`? And better, is there just a nicer all-Julia way to get the effect of `gmtime`?

Comment: Have you looked into the Datetime package? I'd imagine creating a datetime object would get her done in most settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `gmtime` is on Julia's [**TODO**](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/libc.jl#L30) list.  Until it gets included, will something like this work for you?

```
julia> function gmtime(t::Real)
           t = floor(t)
           tm = TmStruct()
           ccall(:gmtime_r, Ptr{TmStruct}, (Ptr{Int}, Ptr{TmStruct}), &t, &tm)
           return tm
       end
gmtime (generic function with 1 method)

julia> strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime(0))
"00:00:00"
```

Comment: Nicely done. Far better to use the `_r` version since the regular `gmtime` when called from C would go who knows where.